# Javascript library for Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

I'm looking for a JavaScript library that does user hit/interface analytics just like Google analytics.

But,...
Im looking for a library that can track or analyse my user hits or interface on my web application and send the report to my function or api then I can choose to store the data in my database or server or anywhere else or it could also be chosen to store offline, instead of a third party server for analysis. Basically I should not be sending that data on to a third party server.

I might as well want the function or api to update the UI based on the users most used interaction immediately or upon arriving at the same page the next time.

So **AFAIK, Google analytics does not do this, hence that's out of the list.**

Is there any such JavaScript library that does this?

Comment: Maybe you can test => [Piwik](http://piwik.org/)

Comment: FWIW, analytics.js by Google Analytics can do this. You just need to override the [`sendHitTask`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tasks) and provide the back end that you want to receive the hit.

Comment: Both of your answers are useful. But @dutycorpse suites better. I can take that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put my comment in answer.

You can try this analytics to do this. => [Piwik](http://piwik.org/)